# Qt: How to create/render Arrow Graphics Item on QGraphicsscene

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

How do we create a Arrow graphics item which gets displayed on a graphics scene? 
My requirement is that I drag and drop a QGraphicsLineItem from one scene to another. Once the Line item is dropped on a scene, a Arrow graphics Item should display perpendicular to the line item dropped on the scene. I should be able to display the Arrow Item on either side of the line. Currently I am able to drop a Line item onto the scene. I need source code for creation of an Arrow item.

```
Can somebody please help me with this scenario?
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible options here. One is to have an image that you load into a QGraphicsPixmapItem and position and rotate it as desired.

The better method would be to create a class inherited from QGraphicsItem, and draw the arrow in its paint method, with the calls to drawLine.

When you inherit from QGraphicsItem, make sure that you overload the boundingRect() function, as well as the paint() function.